# Output with print and EOF not working

Tags: php, html

```
 print <<< HERE
 <p>
 <img src="dado_$roll.png"
      alt="$roll"
      height="100px"
      width="100px" />
</p>
HERE;
```

Above code is not working. I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: You're getting this aren't you `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in...`?

Comment: -1 for qn title **problems about php?**

Answer (score 2):

There needs to either have a carriage return or a closing `?>` tag after the closing  `HERE;` identifier. See the comments in code.

```
<?php
print <<< HERE
 <p>
 <img src="dado_$roll.png"
      alt="$roll"
      height="100px"
      width="100px" />
</p>
HERE;
// make sure there's a carriage return here
// or add a closing ?> tag
```

You could even have a `//` with nothing else, just as along as there is something under `HERE;`

Otherwise, it will throw: (*and* that's if [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is ON)

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in...(path/to/file) on line X

---

- [**Consult the manual on heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

---

**Edit:** (test output)

```
$roll = "Roll_tag_text";

print <<< HERE
 <p>
 <img src="dado_$roll.png"
      alt="$roll"
      height="100px"
      width="100px" />
</p>

HERE;
```

HTML source: (if this is the desired result)

```
<p>
 <img src="dado_Roll_tag_text.png"
      alt="Roll_tag_text"
      height="100px"
      width="100px" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less confusing and does the same thing: Keep in mind that when using `"` double quotes PHP will allow variables inside of them and their values are used.

```
<?php

 $string = '
   <p>
      <img src="dado_$roll.png"
        alt="$roll"
        height="100px"
        width="100px" />
   </p>
 ';

echo $string;
```